# Beamer - ```\onslide``` not working

Tags: tables, overlays

```
            \begin{tabular}[t]{lcccc}
                \toprule
                \multicolumn{1}{c}{ } & \multicolumn{4}{c}{(ATT)}\\
                \cmidrule(l{3pt}r{3pt}){2-5} 
                \multicolumn{1}{c}{ } & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(C/S)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(TWFE)} \\
                \cmidrule(l{3pt}r{3pt}){2-3} \cmidrule(l{3pt}r{3pt}){4-5}  
                & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4)\\

                \midrule
                %
                \onslide<1->{
                \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textit{Panel A: Main}} &&& \\
                
                & 0.0013 & 0.0014 & 0.0018 & 0.0021\\
                & [$-$0.0602, 0.0628] & [$-$0.0549, 0.0577] & [$-$0.0237, 0.0274] &  [$-$0.0188, 0.0231]\\
                WCB p-val. & - & - & 0.8859 & 0.9209\\
                %
                \midrule
                }
                \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textit{Panel B: Treatment assignment in grade 4}} &&& \\
                & $-$0.0268 & $-$0.0184 & $-$0.0224 & $-$0.0189\\
                & [$-$0.0619, 0.0084] & [$-$0.0543, 0.0175] & [$-$0.0308, $-$0.0139] & [$-$0.0290, $-$0.0088]\\
                WCB p-val. & - & - & 0.2923 & 0.3183\\
                %
                \midrule
                %
                \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textit{Panel C: Stricter definition of success}} &&&\\
                & $-$0.0211 & $-$0.0159 & $-$0.0410 & $-$0.0406\\
                & [$-$0.0859, 0.0437] & [$-$0.0737, 0.0419] & [$-$0.0490, $-$0.0330] & [$-$0.0549, $-$0.0263]\\
                WCB p-val. & - & - & 0.0460 & 0.1301\\
                %
                \midrule
                N  & 22,895 & 22,895 & 22,895 & 22,895\\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
```

I want to display panels subsequently but failed to do so using the `\onslide` and `\only` commands in a beamer environment. They lead to multiple error messages of the sort `Misplaced \omit. \end{frame}` and `Missing \cr inserted. \end{frame}`

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\pause` like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
    \begin{tabular}[t]{lcccc}
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{ } & \multicolumn{4}{c}{(ATT)}\\
        \cmidrule(l{3pt}r{3pt}){2-5} 
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{ } & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(C/S)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(TWFE)} \\
        \cmidrule(l{3pt}r{3pt}){2-3} \cmidrule(l{3pt}r{3pt}){4-5}  
        & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4)\\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textit{Panel A: Main}} &&& \\
        & 0.0013 & 0.0014 & 0.0018 & 0.0021\\
        & [$-$0.0602, 0.0628] & [$-$0.0549, 0.0577] & [$-$0.0237, 0.0274] &  [$-$0.0188, 0.0231]\\
        WCB p-val. & - & - & 0.8859 & 0.9209 \pause\\ 
        \midrule 
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textit{Panel B: Treatment assignment in grade 4}} &&& \\
        & $-$0.0268 & $-$0.0184 & $-$0.0224 & $-$0.0189\\
        & [$-$0.0619, 0.0084] & [$-$0.0543, 0.0175] & [$-$0.0308, $-$0.0139] & [$-$0.0290, $-$0.0088]\\
        WCB p-val. & - & - & 0.2923 & 0.3183 \pause\\
        \midrule 
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textit{Panel C: Stricter definition of success}} &&&\\
        & $-$0.0211 & $-$0.0159 & $-$0.0410 & $-$0.0406\\
        & [$-$0.0859, 0.0437] & [$-$0.0737, 0.0419] & [$-$0.0490, $-$0.0330] & [$-$0.0549, $-$0.0263]\\
        WCB p-val. & - & - & 0.0460 & 0.1301\\
        \midrule
        N  & 22,895 & 22,895 & 22,895 & 22,895\\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}}
    \end{frame}
```

For any details I'd have to refer you to the [Beamer User Guide](https://mirror.informatik.hs-fulda.de/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf). Specifially Section 23.5.